# AWS S3 access policy with object tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is it possible to create an IAM policy in AWS S3 such that a user or group can access only certain objects in an S3 buckets with a specific tag attached to it and all other objects with no tags or different tags in the bucket are not accessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `s3:ExistingObjectTag/<tag-key>`. Using this condition key, you can limit the permission to only on objects that have a specific tag key and value.

For more info, see:

- [Specifying Conditions in a Policy - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html)
- [Object tagging and access control policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html#tagging-and-policies)