# How to write an IAM policy that grants full access on a certain service based on Tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to create a policy that grants full access on some services (ex: lambda, s3, apigateway) based on their tags. The way I think of it is: Only give full access to this resource if it has certain tags (ex: projectName= SpaceX). On the other hand, if a resource doesn't have the desired tags, deny any requests.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

```
{
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : "s3:*",
          "Resource" : "*",
          "Condition" : {
            "StringEquals" : {
              "aws:ResourceTag/env" : "prod"
            }
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow any operation on S3 tagged as `env: prod`

Comment: @MarcIskander Could you please share your IAM policy in the question?

Comment: For s3, it worked when using s3:ExistingObjectTag, and tagging my s3 objects explained here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707600/aws-s3-access-policy-with-object-tags?rq=1) . I was trying to look for something more universal across different resources, but it seems I have to check each service independently.